# Bounds on first place bounty money in a progressive knock out tournament

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization

In Poker, a Progressive knock-out (PKO) tournament is defined as follows:

Players pay $n_1 + n_2$ dollars to enter the tournament, with $n_2$ going to the prize pool and $n_1$ going towards their starting bounty. When you knock out a player, you get paid half of their bounty and the other half is added to your own bounty. When one player stands (all other players have been eliminated), they are also paid their current bounty.

My question is: if $k$ players enter this tournament, what is the smallest and largest amount that this remaining bounty can be? For sake of simplicity, assume that all players are playing at one big table, such that one player can knock out any other player at any given time.

The upper bound is obvious: the maximum is achieved when the last remaining player personally knocks out every other player, which yields a final bounty of $(k+1) \dfrac{n_1}{2}$.

I think the lower bound is achieved as follows: Player $A$ knocks out player $B$, then player $C$ knocks out player $B$, player $D$ knocks out player $C$, and so forth until the last remaining player $X$ knocks out the other player. This yields a final bounty of $n_1 \left( 2 - \dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}} \right)$. Is this right? If so, how can one prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. This can be reformulated as a graph theory problem. Define a DAG $G$ where edges represent player A knocking out player B. The last remaining player $s$ will have an indegree of zero. Then we wish to find bounds on

$$n_1 + \sum_{g \in G \setminus \{s\}} \frac{n_1}{2^{L(s, g)}}$$

where $L(s, g)$ is the length of the path from $s$ to $g$.

The upper bound is obvious from this description. The lower bound is far more intuitive now and can probably be proven rigorously by showing that the greedy choice of adding a vertex at the end is the optimal one.